# Is there a straightforward way to get mismatches/indels in a BAM file using pysam?

Tags: sam

Ideally, I'd like to do something like the following:

```
f = pysam.AlignmentFile(filename, index_filename=index_filename)
read = list(f.fetch('Chromosome', 1, 10000))[0]
read.get_variations()
```

And have that output something like:

```
[
  (1, 'A', 'C'), # An A -> C mismatch at position 1
  (15, 'I', 'CGGG'), # An insertion of the string 'CGGG' starting at position 15 of the read
  (32, 'D', 4), # A deletion of 4 base pairs starting at position 32
]
```

I know that it's possible to figure out all of those values by parsing the CIGAR string and MD tags but I'm wondering if there's a more intuitive interface.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `pileup`, which is the htslib (and thus samtools/bcftools) method for finding variants. See [this section](https://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#introduction) of the pysam documentation. You may want to peruse about [the output](https://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pysam.PileupColumn) as well. The gist is:

```
import pysam
samfile = pysam.AlignmentFile("ex1.bam", "rb" )
for pileupcolumn in samfile.pileup("chr1", 100, 120):
    for pileupread in pileupcolumn.pileups:
        if not pileupread.is_del and not pileupread.is_refskip:
            # query position is None if is_del or is_refskip is set.
            ...handle mismatches...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think this would work but it's less than ideal since I would be iterating over each read multiple times, no? I'm wondering if it's possible to iterate over the list of reads that span a region and retrieve that same information without going over pileup columns.

Comment: Also, this bit of code `for pileupread in pileupcolumn.pileups` crashes the Python kernel when running inside of an IPython notebook :-/